# WinPhone 8 authorization to Skydrive Skydrive

Tags: windows-phone-8, authorization, onedrive

I'm writing an app, that can upload files to Skydrive using http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/SkyDrive_-_How_to_upload_content_on_Windows_Phone.
On my own phone authorization works excellent, but on another device displays the error:[image]

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: are you using the same credentials for both the devices?

Comment: If you mean MS accounts - they are different. If not, please, explain what you mean.

Comment: yeah I meant the MS accounts. When you register your app for the Live SDK I guess you can only use those credentials to login. Till you submit the app to the store you won't be able to check with other credentials. Have a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631823.aspx

Comment: Thank you! I uploaded the app to store and download it to devices. On my own device it works but on another don't.

Comment: Try sign in with your data connection without wifi,

Comment: Yes, I tried sign in with wifi and 3g-internet on phone. Internet is working and I can sign in in another apps.

Comment: Thank you! I found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding capability ID_CAP_NETWORKING in the WMAppManifest.xml file and it work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean with "another device"?! Do you mean a hyper-v machine or a different physical device? In the hyper-v machines you cannot use a MS account.

Do you use single-sign on in your code and do you have your MS account on the second device?

A little more information from you would be good.

UPDATE: Just checked the link of you, and yes you use the scope wl.signin which means single sign on. So the question is: Are you logged in with your MS account on the second device?

Comment: Thank you for answer! Another device is a different physical device with another MS account/

Comment: Yes, I logged on another device. Can you say more about single- and multiple-sign on?

Comment: When you use your app and execute the login code a page shall appear where you have to accept,  that the app has the rights which you defines in your scopes. (wl.xxx) The scope wl.signin for example stands for single sign on, which means (and I tried the same yesterday) you login in just once and after this, everytime you debug (or later run) your app, your credentials will not be requested.

Comment: Thank you! If I understand right, I need to remove scope "wl.signin" and app will be work?

Comment: No that is not what I meant. I'd like to comment the Dialog above but I'm not allowed to do this. Maybe it is as Kulasangar said, and you can only use the credentials you used when registered your app for OneDrive. Simple check for that: On the second device: Connect the device with your MS Account and try again the debugging.

Comment: I don't need to debug it. I uploaded the app to store and download it to devices. On my own device it works but on another don't.

Comment: After last update, where I remove "wl.signin" it don't work too.

Comment: Just a thought, in the Nokia example they have added just the wl.skydrive_update scope. In my app I have both wl.skydrive_update and wl.skydrive scopes, and it works on other devices...

Comment: No, look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243646.aspx The Update scope contains the whole wl.skydrive permissions and additionally the skydrive.

Comment: Thank you! I found the solution.